# Utilizing power automate to create new site collection utilizing SharePoint list for new requests

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Hello everyone I am trying to automate a site creation process, currently it is accepting a input from a list on SharePoint but i am receiving two issues.

1. 400 error, below is the code i am utilizing.
2. i am trying to utilize my drop down option for the webtemplate using json if statements. can someone please help me fix my error and the correct syntax for the json.
   [image: ![enter image description here]

```
{
"request":{
"Site Name":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}",
"Url":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/NewURL']}",
"Lcid":1033,

"Owner":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Primary_x0020_SCA/Email']}"
"webtemplate": "=if(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_App']} =='Team' ||@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_App']}=='Communication' || @{triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_App']} =='Organizational' || @{triggerOutputs()?['body/Web_x0020_App']} == 'Collaboration', 'STS#0', 'SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0', 'STS#3', 'Group#0')",
"WebTemplate":"STS#3",}
}
```

Current error code

```
  "status": 400,
  "message": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n\r\nclientRequestId: 38f2c7cf-ed8d-441b-9c89-c79bd6f5e6f9",
  "source": "https://domain-admin.com/_api/SPSiteManager/create",
  "errors": []
}
```

Comment: You cannot write if statements in body like this. You can create a variable for web template name & set its value inside "condition" action.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you give me an example please, im assuming new step condition "web app" equals "team", then another one equals "communication". any idea why I'm getting a 400 error when trying to create the new site collection?